# Style/usage with conjunctions

Tags: commas, writing-style, conjunctions

A) The modelling data can be reintroduced if needed, for example, if a new variant of concern arises.

B)The modelling data can be reintroduced if needed if a new variant of concern arises.

If **for example** is being used correctly in this instance should it require a semi-colon and comma to be accurate usage or is it acting as an interjection rather than a conjunction as the sentence works without it?

Comment: I like the semicolon idea. Also: if, for example, a new variant of concern arises.

Comment: I'd separate the if-clauses here. B') 'If a new variant of concern arises, the modelling data can, if needed, be reintroduced.' And I'll make an attempt at A': 'To take an example: if a new variant of concern arises, the modelling data can, if needed, be reintroduced.'